# setTimeout still runs when clearTimeout has been called Javascript

Tags: settimeout, cleartimeout

I've had problems like this before in the past. I can't seem to figure out what on earth I seem to be doing wrong here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
<style type="text/css"> 
div#rightSideContent {
width:48%;
height:100%;
float:right;
margin-left:10px;
position: relative;
}
span.explain_pass {
background:#111111;
color:#b4b4b4;
position: absolute;
top:-150px;
left:-17px;
padding:10px;
width:200px;
opacity: 0.9;
border-radius:5px;
}
span.explain_pass:after {
content: ' ';
position: absolute;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%);
bottom:-19px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
border-right: 15px solid transparent;
border-top: 20px solid #111111;
}
div#content {
width:100%;
margin: 300px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var showHint = { 

 timeOut : null,

 hint : function(obj) {
clearTimeout(showHint.timeOut);

showHint.timeOut = null;
 var explain_pass = document.createElement("span");
explain_pass.setAttribute("id","explain_pass");
explain_pass.classList.add("explain_pass");
explain_pass.textContent = obj.dataset.title;

if(!document.getElementById('explain_pass')) {
document.getElementById('rightSideContent').appendChild(explain_pass);
}





if(showHint.timeOut == null) {
document.getElementsByClassName('questionMark')[0].addEventListener('mouseleave',function() {

    console.log(showHint.timeOut);
    showHint.timeOut = setTimeout(function(){

        try{
           document.getElementById('rightSideContent').removeChild(document.getElementById('explain_pass'));
        }
        catch(e) {}



    },3000);


    }  );


    }
    }
     }

    window.onload = function() {

document.getElementsByClassName('questionMark')[0].addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
showHint.hint(this);
});

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="content">
   <div id="rightSideContent">

  <label for="password" class="inputColumn">Password <span 
  class="required">*</span> <span class="questionMark" data-title="Must 
  contain at least 2 characters long including lowercase characters, 
  uppercase characters, and numbers"><svg width="20" fill="#333333" 
  height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="pointer- 
   event:none;" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M504 256c0 136.997-111.043 
   248-248 248S8 392.997 8 256C8 119.083 119.043 8 256 8s248 111.083 248 
  248zM262.655 90c-54.497 0-89.255 22.957-116.549 63.758-3.536 5.286-2.353 
  12.415 2.715 16.258l34.699 26.31c5.205 3.947 12.621 3.008 16.665-2.122 
  17.864-22.658 30.113-35.797 57.303-35.797 20.429 0 45.698 13.148 45.698 
  32.958 0 14.976-12.363 22.667-32.534 33.976C247.128 238.528 216 254.941 
  216 296v4c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h56c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-1.333c0- 
   28.462 83.186-29.647 83.186-106.667 0-58.002-60.165-102-116.531- 
   102zM256 338c-25.365 0-46 20.635-46 46 0 25.364 20.635 46 46 46s46- 
   20.636 46-46c0-25.365-20.635-46-46-46z"/></svg></span> <input 
   name="password" class="passRestrict" id="password" type="password" 
   placeholder="Password" maxlength="255" autocomplete="off" /> <span  
    class="showHidePass">show</span></label>

</div>

<div>
</body>
 </html>
```

I clear the timeout at the begining of the hint script, but the timeout still runs and ends up removing the hint box, even though my mouse hasn't left the object that I was hovering over. Any tips and help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jon W

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], that also shows how you are calling these object methods.

Comment: I would add more console.log() statements to ensure that showHint.hint() is executed, mouseleave executed, etc

Comment: Any other ideas?